# How to use string variable as table name in SQLite Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, sqlite-net

I am getting table name and it's column name from server.
How I can convert string variable to Table name, below is my code.
Below is the code that is working, where User_Information is Table name.
I am using **C# Xamarin Monodroid**.

```
  using SQLite;     
  SQLiteAsyncConnection mDatabase;

  var userData = await mDatabase.QueryAsync<User_Information>("SELECT name FROM [User_Information]", "");
```

Now I have requirement where I am getting table name and column as variable like below

```
  string table_name='User_Information';
  string column_name = "name";

  var userData = await mDatabase.QueryAsync<table_name>("SELECT "+column_name +" FROM ["+table_name+"]", "");
```

in this case I am getting compile time error cannot convert String to SQLite.TableMapping, how to handle such case. I need **async-await** also.

I got one solution also, but I am not able to use **await** that I really want. below is the code

```
  using Android.Database.Sqlite;
  using Android.Database;

  private async void GetTableDataDynamically()
    {
         string table_name='User_Information';
         string column_name = "name";

         string sqlQuery = "SELECT " + column_name + " FROM [" + table_name + "]";
            
            SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = SQLiteDatabase.OpenDatabase(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "My_Database"), null, DatabaseOpenFlags.OpenReadonly);
            ICursor selectData = sqliteDB.RawQuery(sqlQuery , new string[] { });
            //How to use await keyword with above query
            if (selectData.Count > 0)
            {
                selectData.MoveToFirst();
                do
                {           
                    var data = selectData.GetString(selectData.GetColumnIndex(column_name));

                }
                while (selectData.MoveToNext());
                selectData.Close();
            }

    }
```

How to use **await** with **sqliteDB.RawQuery**
Please advise if someone knows the solution.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: `QueryAsync<T>` needs a `Type` not ist name. You probably need something like `var 
 tableType = Type.GetType("table_name")` or scan your assembly for existing types, i.e.: `Assembly.GetTypes()`, then filter the return values (something something ` => x.Name == table_name`).

Comment: I already tried var dynamicTableData = await mDatabase.QueryAsync<Type.GetType(tableName)> (sqlQuery, ""); but not works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally things like column names (or table names) can not be parameterised - and the fact that there are different indices means that it will have to be a different plan internally.

So indicating a column name, you can only use it to supply values like the following code:

```
        var param1 = "";
        var param2 = "";
        var packages = await conn.QueryAsync<Package>("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column1 = ? and Column2= ?", new string[2] { param1, param2 });
```

Or one paramter:

```
var allUsers = await conn.QueryAsync<Customer>("Select * From Customer Where CompanyName ='?'", Company);
```